# Use Script to Automatically Update Software on Windows

Tags: windows, automation, auto-update

There are about 20 Windows machines in our office. Each employee log into his station as a regular user not an administrator. The issue is that users cannot update installed software, such as Flash and Java, because they don't have administrator access.

I hope to find a way to write some scripts to automatically update these software for all the machines.

I'm not a windows expert. I'll appreciate any advises and ideas.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) Python framework. It's very simple to understand. But you may have some problems with Flash and Java buttons recognition. So you can use ClickInput(coords) method for dialog wrapper, because install wizard pages and their sizes are often fixed. Feel free asking questions by tag `pywinauto`. I'm monitoring them.

When the scripts are ready, you need to automatically login to each of 20 remote machines with RDP or VNC software and run them. Just do not minimize and do not close each Remote Desktop or VNC window (focus can be safely lost) for keeping GUI context.